# Where can I find premade characters for D&D 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-sheets

I'm going to play D&D 4e tomorrow, and I don't have the time to make my own character.

Does anyone know a place where I can find premade character sheets that people have shared?

Comment: Ask your DM if he has a premade character he keeps around for new people.

Comment: A search for "character pregen" turned up [this pregenerated character library for 4e](http://dungeonsmaster.com/pre-generated-character-library/). Someone (more versed in 4e than I am) may want to include it in a more comprehensive answer about where to find pregens.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend a combination of the wizard's community and the character builder from DDI.

The [Class Guides](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19649074/The_Complete_Collection_of_Character_Build_Links) have both pregenerated characters and everything you need to make decent choices quickly. When combined with the [Character Builder](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/characterbuilder), you can make a high quality character that fits your requirements (to a degree, due to haste) quite quite quickly. Furthermore, making a level 1 essentials character is trivial in the extreme, especially using the guide. Finally, the CB has a number of sample characters already in place, though I do disrecommend them.

Assuming that you can generate a sheet with DDI, "pick-up and go" characters include:

- [4 sample thief builds](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/27050849/What_Is_Yours_Can_Be_Mine%3a_A_Thiefs_Handbook?post_num=10#486645241). These are of excellent quality, in terms of the decisions they make, they are simple, and they can be quite fun, due to the thief's mechanics.
- langeweile's [Achilles](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25680621/Achilles_-_a_Battlemind_Build) and [Ronin](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25486489/Ronin_-_a_Battlemind_Build), both of which I've based my own builds on. His level by level breakdown is excellent.
- LordDuskblade's [Stormbringer](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25766477/Stormbringer?pg=1) is also solid and has a level by level breakdown.

In terms of actual sheets, inputting these into the character builder is the matter of 20 minutes, which should be spent as it helps you to become familiar with the builds themselves.

Comment: In addition to those, there is a thread on Wizards 4e CharOp that didn't make it into the class guide thread- [Pregen Characters - Good And Simple](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/29114309/Pregen_Characters_-_Good_and_Simple?pg=1) which you might find useful.  It had level 1, 5, and 8 builds for most classes there.

Answer (score 4):

As @SevenSidedDie indicates in comments there's a good set of pregens to be found at http://dungeonsmaster.com/pre-generated-character-library/

This is a collection of the pregens that WotC provided with the various D&D encounter seasons.

As such, they should be reasonably good choices for players who are new to 4E or to RPGs in general.

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't require buying a DDI subscription if one doesn't want to.

Answer (score 2):

Wizards' [D&D Character Sheet page](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/Tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/charactersheet) has a few low level premades.

Chaotic Shiny has a [D&D 4e character generator](http://chaoticshiny.com/full4e.php).